# How to move failed / stuck workflow to new version after fixed bug?

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow

My understanding is if the bug was in Activity, the new code will be used since Activity does not have the concept of version. But what if there is a bug in Workflow code and causing some workflows to fail (or even worse, not fail but stuck), we fixed the bug and deployed the new version, but those failing workflows are stuck on old versions. Is there a way to automatically move those failed / stuck workflows to new version and re-run them?

This happening a lot to us because we just started to learn to use Cadence/Temporal

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the bug.

For bugs that cause workflow to get stuck (in Go a nil pointer dereferencing causes panic which blocks the workflow progress by default) deploying the new version of the code is usually enough to unblock them.

If the bugfix requires backwards incompatible change then the best option would be to [reset workflow](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/learn-cli#restart-reset-workflow) to the point before the bug. This way workflow will be rolled back and continue through the new code.

For situation when the breakage of workflow code is caused by a new bad build you can rollback the workers to the previous build and mark that build as broken and all workflows going to roll back their state to before that build automatically. See "[Recovery from bad deployment](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/learn-cli#recovery-from-bad-deployment----auto-reset-workflow)" section of the Temporal documentation.

If you are using ElasticSearch integration then you can also perform batch reset of multiple workflows using a predicate to select workflows that match some criteria. See "[Signal, cancel, terminate workflows as a batch job](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/learn-cli#signal-cancel-terminate-workflows-as-a-batch-job)" section. Besides the name of the section the batch jobs apply to reset operations as well.